# Return in condition

Tags: javascript, recursion

Return does not work in condition. Although console.log works fine. Problem is that function always return false.

```
function func(obj, input) {
  if (input === obj) {
    console.log('Here it works');
    return true; //expected return tr
  };

  for (let key in obj) {
    func(obj[key], input);
  }

  return false;
```

}

Comment: best to check what your `obj` and `input` are passing. Maybe you're checking a `Number` and a `String`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of the call inside of the `for` loop and exit with returning `true`.

```js
function contains(obj, input) {
    if (input === obj) {
        return true;
    }

    if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object') { // check for objects
        return false;                      // and exit if not with false
    }

    for (let key in obj) {
        if (contains(obj[key], input)) {  // check for true
            return true;                  // return only if true
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(contains('a', 'a'));
console.log(contains('a', 'b'));
console.log(contains({ foo: { bar: { baz: 42 } } }, '42'));
console.log(contains({ foo: { bar: { baz: 42 } } }, 42));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's working fine

```
    function func(obj, input) {
  if (input === obj) {
    console.log('Here it works');
    return true; //expected return tr
  };

  for (let key in obj) {
    contains(obj[key], input);
  }

  return false;}

var a ={}

console.log(func(a,a));
Here it works
 true
```

Comment: Sorry, I made mistake expcept contains it should be func